After upgrading spring framework 6.0.14 to 6.1.6 getting error in this spell expression
This is the spell expression:
@Cacheable(value = "Cache", 
    key = "(#request).getToken().hashCode()", 
    unless = "#result == null")


ERROR:org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getAuthenticationRequest() on null context object

How do I resolve this issue?

I think the answer is in the Javadocs:
/**
 * Spring Expression Language (SpEL) expression for computing the key dynamically.
 * <p>Default is {@code ""}, meaning all method parameters are considered as a key,
 * unless a custom {@link #keyGenerator} has been configured.
 * <p>The SpEL expression evaluates against a dedicated context that provides the
 * following meta-data:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code #root.method}, {@code #root.target}, and {@code #root.caches} for
 * references to the {@link java.lang.reflect.Method method}, target object, and
 * affected cache(s) respectively.</li>
 * <li>Shortcuts for the method name ({@code #root.methodName}) and target class
 * ({@code #root.targetClass}) are also available.
 * <li>Method arguments can be accessed by index. For instance the second argument
 * can be accessed via {@code #root.args[1]}, {@code #p1} or {@code #a1}. Arguments
 * can also be accessed by name if that information is available.</li>
 * </ul>
 */
String key() default "";

I assume your request is a parameter name. Apparently such an information is not available in your case. Try to compile your project with -parameters option.

I tried compiling project with -parameters and it worked fine. Thanks for help

Great! Now let's look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. This will help community to determine that there is an answer to similar problem they may encounter.
